# How to edit and deploy code without restarting server?

Tags: node.js

I have node server which i run using forever. But each time if I edit my code I'll have to restart the server. I came across the module called hotnode which can perform live edits but will it have the same performance as the forever module or can I run my code using both the modules. I am confused. Any help wil be much helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to nodemon you can use [node-supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor).

I used to use nodemon, but for some reason it didn't detect code changes on my linux box, which supervisor did flawlessly.

The downside is that it doesn't (or at least didn't) give the colorful output nodemon gives.

Comment: nodemon has an option to be used along with forever.But can node-supervisor combined along with forever? because i am using forever in my production deployment.If there is any module that performs both the functionality of forever and live-edits it will be really helpful

Comment: @AmandaG i doubt that as they both serve roughly the same purpose, there's even an [issue asking the same question](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor/issues/27)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon).

> nodemon will watch the files in the directory that nodemon was started, and if they change, it will automatically restart your node application.

Comment: forever is one module that restarts the server even if there is any error say if i hit my nodejs server with wrong request parameters then forever simply restarts my server.will nodemon handle that functionality along with live edit ?

Comment: You can mix nodemon with forever (see the `--exitcrash` option of nodemon)

Comment: I tried nodemon but it did not work in my linux server properly whereas node-supervisor was working fine.Which is the best module for working in production environment?